# Import docx file into emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, ms-word, org-mode, pandoc

I have been scouring the web for hours now and I haven't found a complete answer. I am wanting to convert my .org file to .docx (and docx. to .org) while maintaining the sections and tables. I have found and tried using pandoc through powershell as a tool to do this but I believe I am not doing any thing.

Here is the command I type into pandec:
pandoc report7a.org -s -o report7.docx

Shows the error:

pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xfe': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream

I have little experience with doing stuff like this.

[Here is an image of the .org file I want to convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AjAv.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your editor put the [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) into begin of the file.  Check [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31909/how-to-get-rid-of-bom-byte-order-mark) on how to do it with Emacs.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the coding system for saving the file to UTF-8-emacs by:
C-x C-m f UTF-8-emacs
fixed the export issue.

Last thing, is there a way to have pandoc to transfer over the formatting? So if there is paragraph notation and centering of a block of text done in Word it would be transferred to ,org file?

Comment: I really don't know - I'm not familiar with pandoc

Comment: @CoreySmith, no pandoc doesn't do layout/formatting.